# GitPython: Get current tag (detached head)

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I use the library [gitpython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/)

If the local git is on a checked out tag, I want to get the name of the tag.

```
repo=git.Repo(repo_dir)
repo.tag # --> tags. But which is the current?
```

On the command line, the `git` tool knows it. Example

```
user@host> git status
HEAD detached at release/1.2.3
```

I want to get the string "release/1.2.3" via gitpython.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can iterate through tags and compare each tag commit with current head commit:

```
next((tag for tag in repo.tags if tag.commit == repo.head.commit), None)
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: @AndreyT thank you. the `next()` trick was new to me. It returns the first match or None. For other people: `next(iter([1, 2, 3]), None) --> 1`

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you might be able to get what you want with [GitCmd](https://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=describe#module-git.cmd) calling `describe`.

```
g = Git(git_dir)
rval = g.describe()
```

I don't see any way to directly access this information.

Comment: or with [`repo.git.describe()`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/136).